Model not properly compiled using Tensorflow Keras on Pycharm
I am creating a  bidirectional LSTM model for my text categorization program using Tensorflow v2.17.0 on PyCharm. However, when I compile the model, the output of model.summary() indicates that the layers were unbuilt.
Any suggestions or recommendations on how to fix this?
I am running my code using Python 3.12 on PyCharm 2024.1.4
Here is the code I wrote:
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Bidirectional, Dense, Embedding

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read training data
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', engine='python')

# Retrieve id and comment text from the dataframe
X = data['comment_text']
y = data[data.columns[2:]].values

# Vectorize the text
MAX_FEATURES = 200000 # number of words in the vocab
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=MAX_FEATURES, output_sequence_length=1800, output_mode='int')

vectorizer.adapt(X.values)
vectorized_text = vectorizer(X.values)
# MCSHBAP - map, chache, shuffle, batch, prefetch  from_tensor_slices, list_file
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((vectorized_text, y))
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(160000)
dataset = dataset.batch(16)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(8) # helps bottlenecks
train = dataset.take(int(len(dataset)*.7))
val = dataset.skip(int(len(dataset)*.7)).take(int(len(dataset)*.2))
test = dataset.skip(int(len(dataset)*.9)).take(int(len(dataset)*.1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# Create the embedding layer
model.add(Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, 32))

# Bidirectional LSTM Layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh')))

# Feature extractor Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

# Final layer
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.summary()

It seems that the model has not been compiled properly as the output shows no output shape and 0 parameters built. Here is the screenshot of model.summary():
Output of model.summary()

You have to build the model.

This question is similar to: TensorFlow Keras compilation successful; still model summary is undefined. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
